# LoadError when using ActiveSupport Concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a `load_missing_constant` error when using Concerns. Only if I start rake tasks. Rails server/console starts normally.

```
# app/models/journey.rb
class Journey < CouchRest::Model::Base
  include Searchable
end

# app/models/concerns/journey/payable.rb
module Journey::Payable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def search
      true
    end
  end
end

#application.rb
config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/lib #{config.root}/app/models/concerns )
```

error

> /Users/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@project/gems/activesupport-3.1.8/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:490:in `load_missing_constant': Expected /Users/user/code/project/app/models/concerns/journey/payable.rb to define Journey::Payable (LoadError)

Comment: have you tried wrapping the contents of payable.rb with `module Concerns`?

Comment: Thx for responding. Yes and I get the same error.

Comment: I also have the same problem